# How to create a stream of streams in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm a learner of Akka Stream. I'd like to create a stream of streams in Akka Stream. I know `SubFlow` and try some methods of `SubFlow`, but I can't do what I want to do. The following code represents what I want to do, but it has some problems.

I want to process a stream of streams like the `mapAsync` below code (The process means mapping the stream of streams and running the stream of streams with a sink).

```
// Create a stream of streams
val streamOfStreams: Source[Source[Int, Unit], Unit] =
  Source(1 to 10)
    // concat a stream and Source.single(elem)
  .fold(Source.empty[Int])((stream, elem) => stream ++ Source.single(elem))


streamOfStreams
  // Print elements of the stream of streams by Sink.foreach
  .mapAsync(1){stream => stream.runForeach(e => println("inner " + e))}
  // Print the result of stream.runForeach()
  .runForeach(futureResult => println("futureResult: " + futureResult))
```

The output is here

```
inner 1
inner 2
inner 3
inner 4
inner 5
inner 6
inner 7
inner 8
inner 9
inner 10
futureResult: ()
```

The problem of the code is `fold(Source.empty)(_ ++ Source.single(_))`. Though in this case, the source `Source(1 to 10)` has very few element, actually I want to process a stream with a lot of element. So when a stream has a lot of element, `fold` takes much time and cause error.

So I would like you to tell me how to create a stream of stream. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You have alreay created a stream of stream. Unfortunately you do not share what the error you encounter is, nor what you expect your final result to be.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Very sorry for the late reply. I encountered StackOverflow or something. Because `fold(Source.empty)(_ ++ Source.single(_))` is running until the upstream finishes, the `fold` takes much time, especially source has a lot of element, I think. So I would like to be told the other way that take less time to create a stream of streams.